# hash index on text file

Tags: java, indexing, hash

I have a problem understanding following line:

Create a hash index on text.txt with ids as keys and the full text record as data.

```
 text.txt
 000000010:<status> <id>000000010</id> <created_at>2012/03/11</created_at> <text>@joerogan Played as Joe Savage Rogan in Undisputed3 Career mode, won Pride GP, got UFC title shot against Shields, lost 3 times, and retired</text> <retweet_count>0</retweet_count> <user> <name>Siggi Eggertsson</name> <location>Berlin, Germany</location> <description></description> <url>http://www.siggieggertsson.com</url> </user> </status>
 000000011:<status> <id>000000011</id> <created_at>2012/03/11</created_at> <text>Cat and Metronome: http://t.co/3Z7Aq8Dn</text> <retweet_count>3</retweet_count> <user> <name>Siggi Eggertsson</name> <location>Berlin, Germany</location> <description></description> <url>http://www.siggieggertsson.com</url> </user> </status>
 ...
```

I am not sure what I am supposed to do.

Should I make another txt file for storing hash index? 
It looks like id is unique for each line and I do not even need to hashing in this case.
Can I do this with db_load command?

Thanks for help in advance!

Comment: Smells an awful lot like homework. How about asking your teacher what she meant?

Comment: @GreyBeardedGeek sry. if it bothered u

Comment: You didn't 'bother' me.
I was suggesting that the thing that you do not understand is the assignment that you were given, and that you would get the best answer by asking the person who gave you the assignment what they meant.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of an index is to speed lookups on a set of data. So in this case I would expect to be able to use your index to do fast lookups of records from your text file. The index would hypothetically be composed of a tuple consisting of the record id, along with the offset in the file where the corresponding record begins.

It would probably be best to store the index in a separate file - you could give it a name that matches up with the file being indexed (text.idx for example).